# How to search a specific row to find a specific string in excell files(Apache POi)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am writing a program and I want when I give the program a String name search the excel file and the specific row given for the String in the specific row...For example I have an excel file that is:

names      Chris Pavlov Anton Nick John

And I want when the String variable name is John to find what is the cell value where "John" is in the excel file. So I search the whole 1st row and I find the cell value of the name "John".

I haven't tried anything because I didn't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
```

// initially you have to create a workbook like this..

```
String FilePath = " "; // input excel file location.
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
```

Get access to the sheet

```
Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
```

get the number of rows present in sheet

```
int totalNoOfRows = sh.getRows();
```

To get the number of columns present in sheet

```
int totalNoOfCols = sh.getColumns();
```

then iterate through excel sheet to find particular data..

```
for (int row = 0; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) {

            for (int col = 0; col < totalNoOfCols; col++) {
                //your comparision code goes here
                // if(sh.getCell(col, row).getContents().equals(yourString) )  

            }
```

Hope this will help you :)..